# Why I need a $scope.$digest in Promise

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-digest

All:

I am pretty new to angular digest, right now, when I use Promise, in its then function, I have to use $scope.$digest() to make scope variable change takes effect on other place, like:

Here I use a Promise to emulate $http request, my confuse is in $scope.getdata, **why I need to call $scope.$digest(), I thought $scope.disable should be watched by angular automatically.**

```
var app = angular.module("vp", []);
app
    .service("srh", function($http){
        var busy = false;
        this.get = function(url){
            if(!busy){
                busy = true;
                var p = new Promise(function(res, rej){
                            $timeout(function(){
                                res("data is fetched");
                            }, 3000);
                        })
                        .then(function(data){
                            busy = false;
                            return data;
                        }, function(data){
                            busy = false;
                            return data;
                        });
                return p;
            }else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    })// end of service
    .controller("main", function($scope, srh){
        $scope.disable = false;
        $scope.getdata = function(){
            var dp = srh.get("");
            if( dp ) {
                $scope.disable = true;
                dp.then(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    $scope.disable = false;
                    $scope.$digest()
                })
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$q` angular promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) which will internally handle all digest requirements.

Whenever you use events outside of angular core that modify scope you need to tell angular so it can update view

Comment: Thanks, I am pretty new to this, could you list what situation can be categorize as that "events"?

Comment: third party library events, dom events , native promises , native timers like setTimeout or things like postMessage. Anything that isn't directly part of the angular api

Comment: note that `$http` uses `$q` to return it's promises also